# Is it possible to archive org-mode agenda entries from a given date range?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

My emacs org-mode agenda files are steadily growing, and many of my projects span several to many years.  In addition, I need to last access the entries after about a year.  Hence rather than (or in addition to) archiving my agenda entries per project, I would like to archive all my agenda entries from a given date range, for example (half) a calendar year.  Is this possible somehow?  Since I need to do this once or twice a year, it isn't too bad if I need more than a few keystrokes for this action (which I could stick in a macro anyway).  Even if the solution would only work for a given month or calendar year, rather than any random date range, it would help me.

My work agenda file has a structure like below.  I would like that structure to be kept in the archive file, in case I ever need to figure out how much time I spent on a given project or on all my teaching years later.

```
* Research
** Project 1
*** Task 1 (with timestamp below)
<2023-07-19 Wed 11:40>
*** Task 2
<2023-07-19 Wed 11:41>
*** Etc
** Project 2
*** More tasks with timestamps
** Project N
* Teaching
** Class 1
*** Even more tasks with timestamps
** Class 2
*** More tasks with timestamps
```

Comment: How about conducting a search for a specific date range, then mark the ones within that search result that you want to archive (or all of them), and then archive them?  Here is a link to some advanced searching techniques from the manual:  https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html  See also the agenda individual / bulk marking commands in the manual:  https://orgmode.org/manual/Agenda-Commands.html

Comment: @lawlist That looks pretty powerful.  However, I was hoping to keep the structure from the original file in my archive file.  I hadn't realised sufficiently how essential that is to my wishes and hadn't specified it in the question, so I just added it.

Comment: How do you store the dates (that is to say, how could I know that an entry is eligible for this archiving?

Comment: @Trevoke  Orgmode agenda uses timestamps formatted like `<2023-07-19 Wed 11:40>`.

Comment: @AstroFloyd what I mean is, where is the timestamp? a property? the body?

Comment: @Trevoke I think I'm just using the default formatting, but I added a couple of example tasks and their timestamps in my "code" in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a command-line tool written in Python called `org-agenda-archive` that (crudely) does what I wanted and published it on [GitHub](https://github.com/MarcvdSluys/org-agenda-archive).